# How to add 1 day from a user defined date in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

What I understood in SQL is if you add 1 day from today's date, you can use

```
SELECT @date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 112)
```

but my issue is, I am not getting today's date. I have a user defined field for date which I was the one who set this date.

Example: my column is name is "Return Booked", how shall I add 1 day to every return booked I have set?

[See attached: SQL Server result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8bdQ.jpg)

Also, if I try to use CONVERT (DATEADD, *****) I have an error below:

How to deal with the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My current SELECT statement is

```
SELECT dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo.UserDefined6 AS ReturnBooked
```

Note that the data type of UserDefined6 is nvarchar. :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `GETDATE`() in the snippet to your value, and it is not a good practice to keep date values in `nvarchar`, so you will need some conversion first.
something like that:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, 1, (CONVERT(DATETIME,UserDefined6))),112) AS ReturnBooked
FROM dbo.AdditionalDetailInfo
```

Comment: Can you also suggest an improvement, what if in the long run I've changed my mind not to put +1 day to this field. What part of the code I need to delete? Many thanks!

Comment: @TrishFernandez You can use `CONVERT(DATETIME,UserDefined6) + 1` if you want +1 day.

Comment: Dishant, I am getting an error " The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type has created a value out of range".

Comment: @TrishFernandez  DATEADD is responsible for adding days, so to not put +1 day just remove,  ex from:
DATEADD(DAY, 1, (CONVERT(DATETIME,UserDefined6))),112)

TO only

CONVERT(DATETIME,UserDefined6)

Answer (score 1):

As datatype of your column is `nvarchar`, `Dateadd` function on nvarchar will fail, so First you need to `convert` the column value to `datetime` and then use the `DateAdd` function, like below

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(Datetime,ReturnBooked))
```

After looking at the image of sample data, it seems you have a row with date text in wrong format `08/010/2018`. The conversion will fail for this particular row, so recommended to fix such bad data.

Comment: Can you also suggest an improvement, what if in the long run I've changed my mind not to put +1 day to this field. What part of the code I need to delete? Many thanks!